Не отображается StyleSheet в Qt Designer
Создаю программу в Qt Designer. 
Добавил стили к listWidget.
В тестовом режиме он выглядит так:

QScrollBar выглядит, как надо.
Но если перейти в превью режим, то выглядит так:


Стили не работают в превью режиме и в уже сконвертированном в py файл тоже.
Прикладываю стили:
QListWidget {
    
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    
    color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
;
}

/* Стиль вертикального ползунка */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: 1px solid rgb(25, 26, 28);
    background-color: rgb(25, 26, 28);
    width: 15px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(40, 47, 53);
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;

}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;

}

/* Убираем стрелки по краям ползунков */
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical,
QScrollBar::left-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal {
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal,
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}


/* Стиль горизонтального ползунка */
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid rgb(25, 26, 28);
    background-color: rgb(25, 26, 28);
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: rgb(40, 47, 53);
    min-width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    border: none;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    border: none;

}


Прикладываю .ui файл:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>504</width>
    <height>787</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">#centralwidget{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.361519, y1:0.966, x2:0.355, y2:0.0568182, stop:0 rgba(25, 26, 28, 255), stop:0.293233 rgba(50, 57, 65, 255));}
</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">#widget{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.361519, y1:0.966, x2:0.355, y2:0.0568182, stop:0 rgba(25, 26, 28, 255), stop:0.293233 rgba(50, 57, 65, 255));}</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
       <item>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
          <item>
           <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>257</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true"/>
            </property>
            <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
             <item>
              <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
               <property name="orientation">
                <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
               </property>
               <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                <size>
                 <width>40</width>
                 <height>20</height>
                </size>
               </property>
              </spacer>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>60</width>
                 <height>61</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="maximumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>60</width>
                 <height>16777215</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">#pushButton_2 {
    background-color: rgb(40, 47, 53);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    
color:rgb(229, 229, 229);
border-radius: 30px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#pushButton_2:hover{
background-color: rgb(24, 100, 71);
}</string>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>✖</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>251</width>
                 <height>247</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;</string>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string/>
               </property>
               <property name="pixmap">
                <pixmap resource="../../../Downloads/test.qrc">:/testphoto/11zon_cropped.png</pixmap>
               </property>
               <property name="alignment">
                <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>60</width>
                 <height>61</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="maximumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>60</width>
                 <height>16777215</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">#pushButton {
    background-color: rgb(40, 47, 53);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    
color: rgb(171, 213, 213);
border-radius: 30px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#pushButton:hover{
background-color: rgb(24, 100, 71);
}</string>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>✚</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
               <property name="orientation">
                <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
               </property>
               <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                <size>
                 <width>40</width>
                 <height>20</height>
                </size>
               </property>
              </spacer>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_4" native="true">
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true"/>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
             <item>
              <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>359</width>
                 <height>435</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="font">
                <font>
                 <family>MS Shell Dlg 2</family>
                 <pointsize>12</pointsize>
                 <weight>50</weight>
                 <bold>false</bold>
                </font>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">QListWidget {
    
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    
    color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
;
}



/* Стиль вертикального ползунка */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: 1px solid rgb(25, 26, 28);
    
     
    background-color: rgb(25, 26, 28);
    width: 15px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(40, 47, 53);
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;

}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;

}

/* Убираем стрелки по краям ползунков */
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical,
QScrollBar::left-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal {
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal,
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}


/* Стиль горизонтального ползунка */
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid rgb(25, 26, 28);
    background-color: rgb(25, 26, 28);
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: rgb(40, 47, 53);
    min-width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    border: none;

}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    border: none;

}</string>
               </property>
               <property name="horizontalScrollMode">
                <enum>QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerItem</enum>
               </property>
               <property name="layoutMode">
                <enum>QListView::SinglePass</enum>
               </property>
               <property name="spacing">
                <number>5</number>
               </property>
               <property name="viewMode">
                <enum>QListView::ListMode</enum>
               </property>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Linkin park FEOFOLFKFLSREfwrefredfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>sfsefse</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>fse</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>fse</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>fsef</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>serf</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>sef</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>sef</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>sef</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>sef</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>g</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>dtg</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>fth</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>frh</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>ryfhrty</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>h</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>New Item</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>New Item</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Rammstein</string>
                </property>
               </item>
               <item>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>Radio tapok</string>
                </property>
               </item>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="../../../Downloads/test.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>


Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема?

В виджете listWidget оставьте только стили для него:


Стили для ползунка перенесите в MainWindow:


Теперь попробуйте:


@НикитаПфейфер что не так?

Добрый день! Не было возможности проверить. Сейчас посмотрю

Да это решило проблему, спасибо! Но не могли бы вы объяснить, что конкретно изменилось? И как MainWindow повлиял на ползунки ListWidget?

@НикитаПфейфер пожалуйста, ничего не изменилось. Не правильно размещать  стили одного виджета в другом виджете. Лучше все размещать в корне, т.е. в  MainWindow
